# .htaccess redirect all pages except the home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have just merged two websites. Site A is now merged with site B.

Site A has got a .htaccess file which redirects all of the content to the new domain where site B is hosted.

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.siteb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is working perfectly, however, I need the homepage of site A not to redirect.

What do I need to add to the code above to make that happen?

Comment: What are the URL variations of the homepage, as in `/` or `/index.html` or `/index.php`? We need to know all of them to prevent them from applying in the more general rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `.*` to `.+` to make sure your regex pattern isn't matcinng landing page:

```
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.siteb.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: This will need more work if the landing page is ever to be something like `index.html`.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` module actually runs before `mod_dir` module thereby `DirectoryIndex` will add `index.html` etc after rewrite rules have run.