# How can I use Apache's mod_rewrite to redirect requests that do not go to the home/index page?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, server

I have two websites. One is a Django App. The other is just a static site.

If someone were to submit https://example.com/more_info

I need to redirect them to **https://example.co/more_info**

**Note the .com vs .co**

But if they just request https://example.com then I serve them the index page.

I've unsuccessfully tried the code below in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(|/)$
Rewriterule (.*) https://example.com/$1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect all pages except the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594507/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-except-the-home-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to redirect every page to https://example.co other than the home/index page. You can do this by:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+) https://example.co/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```