# Redirect all pages except home page htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress website and I'm trying to redirect all pages to a landing page on the same domain except for the home page.
I tried many solutions found around internet but none of them worked.

What I need is:

- Home page and wp-admin page should always be reachable (example.com and examplecom/wp-admin)
- All the other pages should be redirected with a 302 code to example.com/redirect-page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter that would allow you to create an exception with code which handles website redirect based on current configuration.

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-website-redirect/trunk/SimpleWebsiteRedirect.php#L113

Something like this :

```
add_filter(
    'simple_website_redirect_should_redirect',
    function( $should_redirect, $url ) {

        if( home_url() === $url ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $should_redirect;   
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Htaccess : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38594600/19168006

**Edit** : You need to add that code to your theme `functions.php`

This is the second solution: Perhaps not as elegant as a theoretical, functional .htaccess solution (if it exists).

// Redirect entire site except one page ID

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pc_redirect_site', 5 );
function pc_redirect_site(){
    
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $current_post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_page( 9999 )) { // Excludes page with this ID, and also the WordPress backend
        $id = get_the_ID();
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com', 301 ); // You can change 301 to 302 if the redirect is temporary
        exit;
    } 
}
```

If you don’t want to redirect the admin section, remove ! `is_admin()` && Replace http://example.com with the destination you wish to redirect traffic to By default this performs a 301 (permanent) redirect; if you intent for this to be temporary, change 301 to 302    Obviously swap out 9999 for the page ID you wish to exclude.

**Note**, however, that if you aren’t using a child theme and you have auto-updates on, it will likely be overwritten at some point when your theme forces an update and you’ll have to update it again.

More explanition : [here](https://pagecrafter.com/redirect-entire-wordpress-website-except-one-page/)

Comment: I already tried the solution from the other thread you linked but doesn't work.
About the filter, I don't get how it handles the 302 code.

Comment: @Mateo you need to add that to your theme `functions.php` . I just added one more solution.

Comment: The OP said he wanted a solution using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution, but you could try this:

you could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get part of the url:

URL: [www.example.com/abc/de](http://www.example.com/abc/de)

output `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`: /abc/de

Then you can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/redirect-page" />`
to redirect.

So something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/wp-admin") {
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />';
}
```

Comment: But with this I cannot use a redirect code. I was looking for a code to put in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker (you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive):

```
# Redirect all pages except "homepage", "wp-admin" and static assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect-page$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin($|/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ /redirect-page [R=302,L]
```

I've also included "static assets" (images, CSS, JS - anything with a file extension) in the exception, since I imagine `/redirect-page` will need to access these.

And naturally, we need to make an exception for `/redirect-page` itself, otherwise it would result in an endless redirect loop.

The `!` prefix on the regex *negates* the expression, so it is successful when it does not match.

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, unlike the `REQUEST_URI` server variable which does.

---

The above can be reduced to a one-liner if you prefer (at the expense of readability):

```
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|redirect-page|wp-admin($|/.*)|.+\.\w{2,4})?$ /redirect-page [R=302,L]
```